# Cannot add method in js object via prototype property

Tags: javascript, prototype

Here is my code for adding a method in a javascript object. I searched a lot but nothing worked for me. What's wrong??

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script>

var person = new Object();

person.prototype.display=function(){

alert("ok");

}

person.display();

</script>
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: If you want to add it to only one object, you don't have to use the prototype.

Comment: I know Bergi there are other ways but I would like to do it with this as well..any idea..??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function person() {}
person.prototype.display = function(){ alert("ok"); } 
var p = new person();
p.display();
```

EDITED to fix syntax error.

Comment: This does work.But why it did not without a constructor..??

Comment: `function person() {}` creates a first-class object whereas `new Object();` does not.  You can only access the the properties of the prototype from a first class object.  This explanation is more detailed: [stack overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/572897/how-does-javascript-prototype-work)

Answer (score 0):

You can't add a property to *undefined*.

```
var foo = new Object();
foo.prototype; // undefined
Object.getPrototypeOf(foo); // prototype of all objects
```

To create an *Object* with it's own *prototype*, use `Object.create`

```
var proto = {},
    foo = Object.create(proto);
foo.prototype; // still undefined
Object.getPrototypeOf(foo) === proto; // true
```

Alternatively, use `new` with a dummy *function*

```
var Obj = function () {},
    proto = Obj.prototype = {};
var foo = new Obj;
foo.prototype; // again still undefined
Object.getPrototypeOf(foo) === proto; // true
```

Once you have the *prototype* from these last two, you can use it as normal

```
proto.display = function () {console.log('display');};
foo.display();
```

Comment: Can you please help me with my example...I amnew to javascript and I feel like I am lost..

Comment: Choose either code block `2` or `3` from my answer and rename `foo` to `person`, then copy code block `4` and change the _function_ to the action you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to implement prototypical inheritance in javascript 'person' needs to be a function, not an object.

This is a good intro I think - http://alexsexton.com/blog/2013/04/understanding-javascript-inheritance/.

Comment: The above code worked just fine..There was a constructor and then everything was set.. What is the difference between a custom object and the root one..?

Comment: The code 'var foo = new Object()' is essentially the same as saying 'var foo = {}'. There's no prototype property in either, if that makes more sense?

Comment: Thank you.That one was good..